# Object Oriented Bayesian Spam Filtering?

Tags: oop, artificial-intelligence, naivebayes, email-spam

I was wondering if there is any good and clean object-oriented programming (OOP) implementation of Bayesian filtering for spam and text classification? This is just for learning purposes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I definitely recommend [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) which is an *Open Source Data Mining Software* written in Java:

> Weka is a collection of machine learning algorithms for data mining tasks. The algorithms can either be applied directly to a dataset or called from your own Java code. Weka contains tools for data pre-processing, classification, regression, clustering, association rules, and visualization. It is also well-suited for developing new machine learning schemes.

As mentioned above, it ships with a bunch of different classifiers like [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), [Winnow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnow_%28algorithm%29), [C4.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm), Naive Bayes (of course) and many more (see the [API doc](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc/)).
Note that a lot of classifiers are known to have **much better perfomance than Naive Bayes** in the field of spam detection or text classification.

Furthermore Weka brings you a very [powerful GUI](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/gui_explorer.html)…

Answer (score 5):

Maybe https://ci-bayes.dev.java.net/ or http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~javabayes/Home/node2.html?

I never played with it either.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Chapter 6 of [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation of Bayesian filtering in C#: [A Naive Bayesian Spam Filter for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BayesianCS.aspx) (hosted on CodeProject).

Answer (score 2):

[nBayes](http://codecube.net/2009/05/bayesian-filtering-with-c/) - another C# implementation hosted on CodePlex

Answer (score 1):

In French, but you should be able to find the download link :)
[PHP Naive Bayesian Filter](http://xhtml.net/scripts/PHPNaiveBayesianFilter)